# Slide show does not work on my custom WP theme

Tags: wordpress

First I want to thank the WP team and all contributors for such amazing product.

I installed word press and started creating my own theme, however I went into a problem as I am new to Word press and Php development.

I installed a plug in which is a slide show when I put the tag into any of my posts it just done not work. I tried several slide show plug and all give the same result, which mean it is not the plugins problem. Also I tried with another themes and it worked which confirms my first conclusion .

Now I know i did not provide much information but I hope you provide me with some idea or "may be"s or if you want some code I will provided so you can help me with this one :)

Comment: Since you are new to Wordpress and plugins, just to exclude a cause: Are you sure that the plugins are enabled? If I recall correctly, after you install a plugin to WP, by default these are disabled. Second thought: Since most of these slideshow plugins use JavaScript, maybe there's some errors in the browser's console?

Comment: check the console for js errors...right click in chrome and inspect element

Comment: @ArturKäpp Yes the plug-ins are enabled, as it works with other themes so the the problem I guess is in my template.

Comment: speaking of JS I think I realized my problem, I am not sure but I think that I forgot to include JS files in my head.php

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got this working what was missed is some functions in the head.php and the footer.php and those tags are `<?php wp_head(); ?>` and `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` respectively.